# Python conditioning statements showing wrong result (32==0) --> True

Tags: python

Why is python showing (32 == 0) in the following code

A weird result was given when I was testing the following code

```
while not stop:
    results = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('background data/test.png', confidence = 0.9)
    print(len(list(results)))
    print(len(list(results)) == 0)
    if len(list(results)) == 0:
        print('exit loop')
        break
```

The result of the above code is

```
32
True
exit loop
```

`len(list(results))` give the output of `32: int`, but when comparing with `0: int`, True is returned

Comment: You are comparing the length of `result` not `results`

Comment: Why do you think the output of two `list` calls are the same? Try `results = iter(range(3))` and repeat `list(results)` twice in your interactive console.

Answer (score 7):

`pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen` returns a generator, which you exhaust when printing the length initially. To fix this, either convert `results` to a list or remove the debug statements.

This is what is happening:

```py
# results is a generator like below
results = (i for i in range(2))

# by calling list on the generator, we consume/exhaust it.
print(len(list(results)))
# output: 2

# if we try to consume again, the generator is empty
print(len(list(results)) == 0)
# output: True, as the len(list(results)) is 0
```

You can do this instead:

```py
# create a generator again
results = (i for i in range(2))

# consume it by converting generator to list once 
results_list = list(results)

print(len(results_list))
# output: 2

print(len(results_list) == 0)
# output: False, as the len(results_list) is 2
```